# How to run (Casper theme from Ghost) development server locally?

Tags: gulp, yarnpkg, ghost-blog

I am trying to edit a custom casper theme. The casper theme was built from the master file. I took over this existing project from downloading the zip file of installed theme from Ghost dashboard. I want to run the development server locally. In the  root folder I ran `yarn dev`. the output is:

```
    yarn run v1.22.4
    warning casper@2.10.1: The engine "ghost" appears to be invalid.
    warning casper@2.10.1: The engine "ghost-api" appears to be invalid.
    $ gulp
    [16:45:37] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/17goalsmagazine/casper_seventeengoals/gulpfile.js
    [16:45:37] Starting 'default'...
    [16:45:37] Starting 'css'...
    Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
    [16:45:37] Finished 'css' after 858 ms
    [16:45:37] Starting 'js'...
    [16:45:37] Finished 'js' after 65 ms
    [16:45:37] Starting 'serve'...
    [16:45:37] Finished 'serve' after 3.58 ms
    [16:45:37] Starting 'cssWatcher'...
```

after that nothing happened. How can I launch the development server with all the assets?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on the forum: https://forum.ghost.org/t/how-to-run-casper-theme-development-server-locally/12778/2

> If you’re doing local theme development you’ll want to place the theme in the `/content/themes/` directory of your Ghost install. That way you’ll be able to work on it directly and see the changes happen on your development site. More info can be found here: https://ghost.org/docs/install/local/#developing-themes